# Xcode 6 beta CFBundleShortVersionString not found when building

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

My iOS project works perfectly in Xcode 5, i just installed Xcode 6 beta 4 and when I build I get this error :

```
/bin/sh -c .../Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/Script-E830169D18F5E42C00C07847.sh

Print: Entry, "CFBundleShortVersionString", Does Not Exist
Parse Error: Unclosed Quotes
Value Required for Set Command
Print: Entry, "CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist
Parse Error: Unclosed Quotes
Value Required for Set Command
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I doubled checked and CFBundleShortVersionString is in my MyProject-Info.plist file.
Someone got the same problem ?

Comment: Peter's solution was actually what i had to do to fix it!